# Java: Выведение массивов в строку и столбец

Tags: java, массивы

Задача:
Создайте массив из всех чётных чисел от 2 до 20 и выведите элементы массива на экран сначала в строку, отделяя один элемент от другого пробелом, а затем в столбик (отделяя один элемент от другого началом новой строки). Перед созданием массива подумайте, какого он будет размера.

Мой код:

```
public class Task1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] mas1 = new int[9];
    for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i = i + 2) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        if (i == 20) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i = i + 2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
}
```

По итогу, в строке выводятся 2 числа "20" (со столбиком все в порядке).
Если в первом for я меняю условие на `i < 20`, получается вообще ерунда.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1. Массив создан, но не заполнен. 2. Печатать надо значения из массива. 3. Функция печати должна быть одна с параметром (в столбик/в строку).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ты дублируешь команду вывода "20", зачем?
убери строку System.out.println(i); после if(i==20)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все верно.

Comment: не за что))))))